# SingleEmailMessage issue

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

Could someone look into this code, and let me know if they see anything wrong that may be causing a problem? For some reason my email is being successfully send with HTML version, but the text version shows only a blank email. The code is essentially the same for both HTML and Text, also in my template the value I am replacing is correct as well.

```
EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [select Id, DeveloperName, HtmlValue, Body, BrandTemplateId From EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'LTRO_Additional_Documents_Required'];

        //Specify the text content of the email.
        String plainBody = emailTemplate.Body;
        plainBody = plainBody.replace('LTRORequireAdditionalDocumentsCon.apxc', emailBody + 
                                      '<br><br><a href="https://'+SandboxName+'redcross.'+sfdcBaseURL+'force.com/DisasterAssessment/ltrodamageuploadstep?ret=1&cid='+caseid+'">Red Cross Disaster Documentation Upload</a>');

        mail.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);
        mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.id);

        // Specify the content of the HTML email        
        String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HTMLValue;
        htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('LTRORequireAdditionalDocumentsCon.apxc', emailBody + 
                                    '<br><br><a href="https://'+SandboxName+'redcross.'+sfdcBaseURL+'force.com/DisasterAssessment/ltrodamageuploadstep?ret=1&cid='+caseid+'">Red Cross Disaster Documentation Upload</a>');
        //!LTRO_Document__c.Type__c   NewEmail
        mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
        mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.id);


        // Send the email you have created.
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify one of the following combinations in an email:

1. HTMLBody + Template Id
2. PlainTextBody + Templated Id
3. HTMLBody + PlainTextBody

Comment: Ok, so I did test with removing the setTemlateId for both setPlainTextBody and setHtmlbody, but still having the same issue. That should satisfy point 3, right?

Comment: This really depends on the mail client you're using, and basically is down to the client's implementation of RFC 821 and its successors. The client may choose to send an HTML-only version without text, in which case the plainTextBody will indeed be blank/null. You'll need to look at the original source to verify if there was a plain text body.

Comment: I  tested that by commenting out the HTML portion of the code and only sending the Text version. In that case, the text version was showing as expected. I checked in hotmail, and outlook. Then I enabled both HTML and Text, and in hotmail was showing the HTML version but in outlook was blank again. This is where I am confused, does HTML take preference over the Text version of the email?

Comment: I have idea of gmail. In gmail there is option `Show original`. By this I can see plain text also. There may be such type of option in outlook and Hotmail.

Comment: I got the way in outlook for you. In outlook, open the email, click the down arrow next to the reply button, then select View message source. Check out this link: https://help.campaignmonitor.com/plain-text-versions-of-html-emails

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Things just got more confusing. So, in the web version of outlook, I was able to view the email in HTML format. The same email in my desktop version of outlook, is showing blank. I am really confused, is my code working, or is this inbox issue.